# How do you create two subplots that share x axes where only one axes has a 1:1 aspect ratio?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am struggling to figure out how to have stacked subplots in which one subplot shows the data with a 1:1 aspect ratio, the other one doesn't and they both share the x axes. The figure I want looks like this:

[image]

My starting point for this figure has been with this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

ax_top = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax_top.set_aspect(1.0)

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi)
ax_top.plot(x, 5*np.sin(x))

ax_bot = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2, sharex=ax_top)
ax_bot.bar([2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [12, 13, 15, 10, 8])

plt.show()
```

But that produces this:

[image]

I would expect the lower plot to have the same width as the upper plot and the matching x ticks line up between the two plots. I've attempted many things to try to coerce this basic figure into the desired figure, but I seem to be missing some fundamental reason it doesn't work.

How might I make my desired figure using matplotlib?

Comment: I think ax_top.set_aspect(1.0) overrides share x for ax_top

Comment: The ticks still seem to have the same shared range, but the widths don't adjust properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the figure taller so the dimension that gets whitespace is the vertical one:

Just to be clear what is happening here - subplot(2, 1) allocates half the figure for one subplot and half for the other.  If the aspect ratio of a plot makes it narrower then there has to be white space.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 7.5))

ax_top = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax_top.set_aspect(1.0)

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi)
ax_top.plot(x, 5*np.sin(x))

ax_bot = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2, sharex=ax_top)
ax_bot.bar([2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [12, 13, 15, 10, 8])

plt.show()
```

[image]

There are of course other ways to do this, including using the axes grid toolkit: https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/axes_grid1/scatter_hist_locatable_axes.html

Comment: So, I just guess at the figure dimensions as long as it taller than wider?

Comment: Another helpful thing is to set the height ratios of the subplots using the gridspec keyword arguments so that you can controller the relative proportion of space in the figure that the subplots take up.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to adjust the height ratios using the `gridspec_kw` for `subplots()`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax_top, ax_bot) = plt.subplots(nrows=2,
                                     sharex=True,
                                     gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [3, 1]})

ax_top.set_aspect(1.0)

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi)
ax_top.plot(x, 2*np.sin(x))

ax_bot.bar([2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [12, 13, 15, 10, 8])

plt.show()
```

produces:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using Gridspec as it is usually more flexible than plt.
Here is what I am thinking about :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=1, figure=fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0],sharex=ax)


x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi)
ax.plot(x, 5*np.sin(x))
ax2.bar([2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [12, 13, 15, 10, 8])
```

Natacha

Comment: Interesting, that seems to work, but I don't understand why this is any different than the code I shared (functionally speaking). I guess figures handle gridspec objects differently that whatever is happening by default with `add_subplot()`?

Comment: Actually this doesn't work, the top figure doesn't have the correct data aspect ratio.